# Taking the second last row with only one select in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, select

I was trying to select the second last row with SQL Server. So I wrote a query like this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * From Cinema 
WHERE CinemaID!=(SELECT TOP 1 CinemaID 
                 FROM Cinema
                 ORDER BY CinemaID DESC)                      
ORDER BY CinemaID DESC
```

and it did what I need. But I want to do the same thing with only one select.

I read that the *LIMIT* clause in ***MySql*** does that. But I couldn't find any equivalent
of that. So I appreciate any help about finding something useful.

Comment: I like your current solution.

Comment: `LIMIT` is a non-ANSI-standard MySQL-specific extension ...

Answer (score 46, accepted):

To get the 2nd last row in one select:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * From
(select Top 2 * from Cinema ORDER BY CinemaID DESC) x                     
ORDER BY CinemaID
```

It's really only "one" select because the outer select is over only 2 rows.

Comment: This can return incorrect results if the table only has one row.

Answer (score 18):

The best way to do this (and compatible with the ANSI SQL standard), is to use a CTE (Common Table Expression) with the `ROW_NUMBER` function:

```
;WITH OrderedCinemas AS
(
   SELECT 
       CinemaID, CinemaName, 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY CinemaID DESC) AS 'RowNum'
   FROM dbo.Cinema
)
SELECT 
   CinemaID, CinemaName
FROM OrderedCinemas
WHERE RowNum = 2
```

By using this construction, you can get the second highest value very easily - or the fifth hightest (`WHERE RowNum = 5`) or the top 3 rows (`WHERE RowNum <= 3`) or whatever you need - the `CinemaID` values are just ordered and sequentially numbered for your use.

Answer (score 8):

The following doesn't work, explaination of why:
[Using ranking-function derived column in where clause (SQL Server 2008)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1479831/using-ranking-function-derived-column-in-where-clause-mssql08)

I'll keep it here for completeness:

---

```
SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY col) r, *
FROM tbl
WHERE r = 2
```

More info:
http://www.bidn.com/blogs/marcoadf/bidn-blog/379/ranking-functions-row_number-vs-rank-vs-dense_rank-vs-ntile

---

So I think the most readable way of doing it is:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY col) r, * FROM tbl) q
WHERE r = 2
```

Comment: Can't use rank() in the where clause.

Comment: Because windowed functions (like rank()) are only allowed in the select or order by clause.  I tried it ><.

Comment: Ah, you are right : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1479831/using-ranking-function-derived-column-in-where-clause-mssql08

Comment: the part that doesn't work happens to be exactly what i'm looking for. :) i really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 8):

Since this (old) question has not been tagged with a specific SQL-Server version and none of (the very good) answers uses only one `SELECT` clause - for the good reason that it was not possible in old verions - here is one that works only in recent, 2012+ versions:

```
SELECT c.* 
FROM dbo.Cinema AS c                    
ORDER BY CinemaID DESC
OFFSET 1 ROW
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY ;
```

Tested at **[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fffe9/4)**

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM tbl_CompanyMaster 
where Companyid >= (SELECT MAX(Companyid) - 1 FROM tbl_CompanyMaster)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from TABLE_NAME order by COLUMN_NAME desc limit 1,1 ;
```

Where `COLUMN_NAME` should be "primary key" or "Unique"

Comment: The question is about SQL Server. This answer does not seem to work in SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

Two selects but a bit quicker

```
select top 1 * from(
SELECT TOP 2 * From Cinema 
WHERE CinemaID
ORDER BY CinemaID DESC) top2
Order by CinemaID
```

Comment: I'm guessing that that second `DESC` is supposed to be an `ASC`?

Comment: yep went a bit mad with copy and paste.

Answer (score 1):

So, in the spirit of only using one SELECT clause as stated in the OP and thoroughly abusing T-SQL in general, I proffer something I would never, ever recommend using in production that nevertheless satisfies the stated criteria:

```
update Cinema
set Cinema.SomeField = Cinema.SomeField
output inserted.*
from Cinema
inner join 
(
    select top 2 CinemaID, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by CinemaID desc) as RowNum
    from Cinema
) rsRowNum on rsRowNum.CinemaID = Cinema.CinemaID
where RowNum = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

This query will also work for SQLITE

```
SELECT *  From
(select * from Cinema ORDER BY CinemaID  DESC LIMIT 2) AS name                    
ORDER BY CinemaID LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I try above query in PostgreSQL, it worked

Answer (score 0):

You're only using one SELECT statement. A SELECT statement can include an arbitrary (more or less) number of subqueries--correlated subqueries, scalar subqueries, and so on, each with their own SELECT clause. But it's still just one SELECT statement.

If you want to avoid a subquery, you could select the top 2, and skip the one you don't want. That kind of programming is pretty brittle, though. You have to remember what to skip every time; sooner or later, you'll forget.

Comment: Is "SELECT statement" really a technical term? I thought the normal term was "query". And anyway, the OP didn't say "only one SELECT statement", but rather "only one select". That could just as easily mean "only one SELECT clause".

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT field_name FROM (SELECT TOP 2 field_name FROM table_name 
                        ORDER BY field_name DESC)
WHERE rownum = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select top 1* from(SELECT TOP 2 * From Cinema 
                   WHERE CinemaID
                   ORDER BY CinemaID DESC) XYZ
ORDER BY CinemaID
```

where XYZ is not a keyword. It is just a word. And word can be anything.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do that, but:

- the column is different than `id`
- you need to order by some specific column
- can't use `SELECT` on `FROM` clause (if you are using old versions of Hibernate, per example).

You can do:

```
select top 1 * from Cinema
where date < (select MAX(date) from Cinema)
order by date desc
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get second last row from sql table is user **ORDER BY CinemaID DESC** and set **LIMIT 1,1**

TRY THIS

```
SELECT * from `Cinema` ORDER BY `CinemaID` DESC LIMIT 1,1
```

Comment: The question is about SQL Server. This answer does not seem to work in SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
select * from 
(select  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) as R, * from Cinema ) T1
where (select count(*) from Cinema ) - T1.R = 1
```

Comment: Hi Shafi. Welcome to Stack Overflow and thanks for your contribution. But could you please add an explanation even if it is only a brief one. [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Kind Regards.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM record
WHERE record_id=(SELECT max(record_id)-1 FROM record)

Answer (score -1):

Here is my code:

```
SELECT *  From
(select * from table name ORDER BY column name  DESC LIMIT 2) AS xyz                   
ORDER BY column name LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: The op asked for a solution with only one SELECT, but your proposed solution seems to use two SELECTs, just like his