# Select second last row of database

Tags: php, sql

For a school project i'm making a web portfolio.
On my site i'm using a subject: "Projects" on my site these are three colums. My question is to generated them from the last three rows from my database, but i can't get it fixed. Can any body help me?

What i need is to select the last second row from a database so I can display it in my portfolio

Comment: last second row by what `order` . How you define your second last row ?

Comment: Tag the dbms used. Add sample table data and the expected result, and show us your current query attempt.

Comment: Reverse `order`, set `offset` to `1` and `limit` also to `1`. If you provide your current SQL query we will be able to give you exact solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM [table name] WHERE 1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1,1 ;
```

Where id can be auto increment primary key of your table. its Mysql query syntax

Comment: Product specific answer, to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell OP which dbms this is for.

Comment: @jarlh, yep added.
For SQL query syntax, check accepted answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8198962/taking-the-second-last-row-with-only-one-select-in-sql-server