# SQL query to fetch second last row or nth row from the table

Tags: sql, oracle

How we can print the second last row from the table using SQL query.

Comment: Provide some sample table data

Comment: [check this, i think it's a duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8198962/taking-the-second-last-row-with-only-one-select-in-sql-server)

Comment: agreed, the duplicate is about tsql but contains answers that are generic enough to work in ora.