# Getting the second record using EXCEPT

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to get the second record from bottom.
I tried

```
SELECT TOP 2 meetings_id FROM meetings ORDER BY meetings_date DESC 
EXCEPT
SELECT TOP 1 meetings_id FROM meetings ORDER BY meetings_date DESC
```

But there is syntax error in `except`.

When I try to delete `order by` it works but that giving me the second record from the top.

Answer (score 2):

Try using OFFSET and FETCH

```
select meetings_id from meetings ORDER BY meetings_date DESC 
OFFSET 1 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY
```

[OFFSET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-offsets-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

[FETCH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/fetch-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use `EXCEPT` because of some strange requirement or trivia, then you need to put the `TOP` queries into table expressions:

```
SELECT meetings_id FROM 
(
  SELECT TOP (2) meetings_id 
    FROM dbo.meetings 
    ORDER BY meetings_date DESC 
) AS bottom2
EXCEPT
SELECT meetings_id FROM
(
  SELECT TOP (1) meetings_id
    FROM dbo.meetings 
    ORDER BY meetings_date DESC
) AS bottom1;
```

But this is neither intuitive nor efficient.

- Examples: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=faa5b32455a0ffa7272cdc4026d7f7df)
- With showplan comparisons, showing why `EXCEPT` is the worse solution offered thus far: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ec124c32a2e692bb1fb0c00b1c751182)

Answer (score -1):

This solution only works while you have > 1 rows in your table.

```
SELECT TOP 1 meetings_id FROM
(SELECT TOP 2 meetings_id, meetings_date FROM meetings 
 ORDER BY meetings_date DESC) x                     
ORDER BY meetings_date;
```

Based on answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8199178/18620048) link.

You'll probably get an error or empty result since there is no penultimate row. So your query will be faulty in this case.